# codeigniter 4, update model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I connected my codeigniter app with mysql. I created a table model like that:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model{

    protected $table = 'I_user';
    protected $allowedFields = ['email', 'password','active', 'hash'];

}
```

And now in my Controller, I want to update user by changing email for example. How to do that?
My controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;

class Confirm extends BaseController 
{
    public function index($email, $hash)
    {
        if(!isset($email) || !isset($hash)){
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }

        $model = new UserModel();
        $user = $model->where('email', $email)->first();
        if($user['hash'] == $hash){
            // update $user email..
            ??
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in such way:

```
$model->where('email', $user['email'])->set(['email' => 'YourNewEmailAddress'])->update();
```

or

```
$model->update(['email'=> $user['email']], ['email' => 'YourNewEmailAddress']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [update](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html) directly to the model data

```
$data = [
    'email' => 'Yourupdatedemailhere'
];

$model->update($user['email'], $data);
```

Comment: It doesn't work.``` Trying to get property 'email' of non-object  ```

Comment: it will array so $user['emai']

Answer (score 0):

If the Primary key is not "id" in your data-table, then you need to mention that in your Model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'email';
```

Then use:

```
$model->update(['email'=> $user['email']], ['email' => 'newemail@example.com']);
```

Comment: If `primaryKey` is email then no need to write `['email'=> $user['email']],`